# How can i confirm or ignore the friend requests by using facebook graph api?or other method?

Tags: facebook

I can use facebook graph api `friendrequests` to get all friends requests, but how can I 
comfirm or ignore this requests?

I spent much time to check the doc of graph api, but got nothing.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it's impossible to confirm or ignore requests of this kind.
The facebook graph api only let's you access the data, not alter it.

You can however delete app requests.
More info on this on: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/